# How to generate a strong encryption key for TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, membership-provider, tripledes

I'm using the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` and need to store the encryption key.

If I call the providers `GenerateKey` method, is this just a base64 encoded string? If so am I safe to unencode it as such as use the resulting string as a key?

On a slightly different note, is there any problem with using this same key as a salt key when doing one-way hashes? I'm writing a simple membership provider for .net which allows the user to choose the encryption technique (plain, hash, encrypted) so wondered whether it was necessary to make the user specify both a salt key and encryption key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling [GenerateKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.generatekey.aspx) will generate a new, **random**, safe (i.e. not weak) key. It's length (128 or 192) will depend on how your `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` is set up.

> If I call the providers GenerateKey method, is this just a base 64 encoded string?

The format itself is a `byte[]` array since you can only retrieve it from the `Key` property - so it's **not** base64, but can easily be encoded that way if you wish, e.g. `Convert.ToBase64String(algo.Key);`

> If so am I safe to unencode it as such as use the resulting string as a key?

You cannot use a string as a key - not unless you convert it back to a `byte[]`. However you can keep the key as a string between it's uses (if that's any help to your application).

> On a slightly different note, is there any problem with using this same key as a salt key when doing one-way hashes?

If you use the random data as a *key* **or** as a *salt* then there should be no issue. Just don't use the same data for **both** (*and*).

Answer (score 1):

> On a slightly different note, is there any problem with using this
>   same key as a salt key when doing one-way hashes?

Salts are public parameters; and private and symmetric keys should be secret.

> I'm writing a simple membership provider for .net which allows the
>   user to choose the encryption technique (plain, hash, encrypted) so
>   wondered whether it was necessary to make the user specify both a salt
>   key and encryption key.

We would need to see more information on the scheme before answering. In general, I would not feel comfortable allowing a user to choose formats or parameters (other than a password).

Comment: here the "user" is the developer. I certainly would not allow the application user to decide this. So there's nothing wrong with storing the salt alongside the hashed password?

Comment: @Ben: it sounds a lot like a unix password file (a {user, salt, hash} tuple). If so, I would not have a problem with the storage format.